# How to render multiple object as JSON and how to retrieve that object from <g:javascript> in Grails?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, grails

Actually I want to add two select boxes in **results** div using Ajax.I have function called **ajaxFun** for retrieving values for that two select box. I am trying to render multiple objects as JSON.but I dont know how to render and how to retrieve rendered objects from my javascript function.

My GSP page.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><div id="test" onclick="${remoteFunction(controller:'ProjectOperations', action:'ajaxFun', update:'results',onComplete:'getFields(e)',params:'\'filter=\' + escape(this.id)' )}">click me!</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Controller class

```
import grails.converters.JSON

class ProjectOperationsController {

    def ajaxFun(){
                def project="Hill"
                def company="VK"
        def operation=Operation.findAllByProject_name(project)
        def staff=StaffDetails.findAllByCompany_name(company)

        render operation,staff as JSON//am not sure 
    }
}
```

here i want to render two list [operation and staff respectievely..].
Then also I want to know how to retrieve the rendered objects from javascript function.

Javascript function

```
<g:javascript>
  function getFields(e){ 
// here I want to retrieve that two objects.
 } 
 </g:javascript>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller change

```
    render operation,staff as JSON//am not sure
```

to

```
    render [operation:operation,staff:staff] as JSON
```

Then in the javascript

```
 function getFields(e){
    var data = eval("("+e.responseText+")");
    console.log(data.staff);
    console.log(data.operation);
 }
```

In your console you should see the contents of staff then the contents of operations which from the findAll will probably be arrays that you can work with in the JavaScript.

Comment: :-sir again one doubt.I want to add the Staff and Operation values into a combo boxes.how to retrieve the values of that list from the **getFields** function?

Comment: Once you have called eval on the responseText the values of the two lists are in data.staff and data.operation you should then be able to work with them as plain javascript objects.